# Qt: Autogenerated code fails when updating QString

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qstring

I'm modifying the GUI code written in Qt ([LibrePilot](https://www.librepilot.org/site/index.html)). There is a way there to add user classes. They are generated automatically from an XML description.

So this class:

```
<xml>
<object name="RecorderService_RecordDescription" singleinstance="true" settings="false" category="State">
    <description>For Recorder gadget</description>

    <field name="text"      units="char"   type="string"  elements="1"/>

    <access gcs="readwrite" flight="readwrite"/>
    <telemetrygcs    acked="false" updatemode="manual"   period="0"/>
    <telemetryflight acked="false" updatemode="periodic" period="1000"/>
    <logging                       updatemode="periodic" period="100"/>
</object>
</xml>
```

Will be autogenerated into a class that has a one data element contained inside a structure with methods to access it.

```
// Field structure
typedef struct {
    QString text;

} __attribute__((packed)) DataFields;
```

When I try to set the `text` with a new value using `setText` method:

```
void RecorderService_RecordDescription::setText(const QString value)
{
   mutex->lock();
   bool changed = (data_.text != static_cast<QString>(value));
   data_.text = static_cast<QString>(value);
   mutex->unlock();
   if (changed) { emit textChanged(value); }
}
```

I get `SIGABRT` exception.

```
#0  0x00007ffff509ce97 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007ffff509e801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff50e7897 in __libc_message (action=action@entry=do_abort, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff5214b9a "%s\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:181
#3  0x00007ffff50ee90a in malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7ffff5212d88 "free(): invalid pointer") at malloc.c:5350
#4  0x00007ffff50f5e1c in _int_free (have_lock=0, p=0x7ffff5f8c5f0, av=0x7ffff5449c40 <main_arena>) at malloc.c:4157
#5  0x00007ffff50f5e1c in __GI___libc_free (mem=0x7ffff5f8c600) at malloc.c:3124
#6  0x00007fffc798671e in RecorderService_RecordDescription::setText(QString) () at /usr/lib/librepilot-gcs/plugins/LibrePilot/libUAVObjects.so
```

One solution I found is that if I add another field to the `RecorderService_RecordDescription`. I.e. the XML is like this:

```
<xml>
<object name="RecorderService_RecordDescription" singleinstance="true" settings="false" category="State">
    <description>For Recorder gadget</description>

    <field name="text"      units="char"   type="string"  elements="1"/>
    <field name="seconds"   units="sec"    type="uint32"  elements="1"/>

    <access gcs="readwrite" flight="readwrite"/>
    <telemetrygcs    acked="false" updatemode="manual"   period="0"/>
    <telemetryflight acked="false" updatemode="periodic" period="1000"/>
    <logging                       updatemode="periodic" period="100"/>
</object>
</xml>
```

The error goes away. The autogenerated class has this data structure:

```
// Field structure
typedef struct {
    quint32 seconds;
    QString text;

} __attribute__((packed)) DataFields;
```

The code for `setText` is the same.
This error didn't happen before when we used an older version of gcc. Current version is 7.2.

Anyone has ideas why the error is happening and how to fix it elegantly.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the code is autogenerated has no bearing on the question. What you're saying is that you have a very short code fragment that supposedly fails: move it to a separate `main.cpp` as a test case! My bet is that you have other problems in the code, and that's why it fails. One of the problems you have is that `__attribute__((packed))` is essentially you kindly asking the compiler to give you some undefined behavior - you don't need that attribute, because the way it works is not the way you think it works. Correct implementation of this attribute shouldn't generate records with insufficiently aligned members, and thus there may still be platform-specific padding added - you just assume it won't be. And anyway: `QString` isn't something that you can dump to disk, so packing this struct makes no sense. Gcc has, in some cases, implemented this attribute incorrectly and that may lead to the behavior you observe, although not in the specific case of the struct you show. Probably some other packed struct ended up corrupting the program state and caused the crash you see. First of all: make a stand-alone test case. Then we can figure out what went wrong. But, above all: **Do not use `__attribute__((packed)`. It's useless for its typical use: serialization.** If you want to serialize/deserialize binary data, use `QDataStream` or a similar mechanism.

Comment: I don't use `__attribute__((packed))`. It comes out from the autogenerator. In addition, `gcc` ignores it saying it is not valid for non-POD type. I'll try to make a standalone case, but working with QT isn't exactly easy.